# Why didn't Wolverine take Quicksilver with him to Paris?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In *X-Men: Days of the Future Past* movie, the primary mission of Wolverine was stopping Mystique from killing Trask. With the help of Quicksilver, couldn't he achieve this within 0.0001 second? This looks easier than breaching the Pentagon.

They never even needed to identify Mystique. All Quicksilver needed was to be around Trask until someone shoots a bullet at him, divert the bullet and capture the shooter. Done!

Why exactly did Wolverine and company avoid using Quicksilver for this mission?

Comment: I think, driving Xavier's car back home wasn't that important. And, Xavier without power was better for this job. :)

Comment: Out of universe, it was because Quicksilver was added almost at the last minute of production. I'll have to dig up the quote I recently read.

Comment: they added him because the had that teaser of quick silver at the end of the captain america movie. ( i believe) since its diffrent companies that own xmen vs avengers/captain america technicly in the 3rd captain movie that will have quicksivler (supposidly) they wont be able to use the word mutant or actually call him quicksilver since (fox?) has the rights to those names.

Comment: Can't find the original article, but [here](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Juggernaut-Almost-Looked-Like-X-Men-Days-Future-Past-43494.html) and [here](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=54666) are some info about how it was originally supposed to be The Juggernaut in the breakout.

Comment: Of course, I found the info right after posting. [This article](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/X-Men-Days-Future-Past-Deleted-Juggernaut-Scene-Has-Been-Revealed-66449.html) goes over that it was changed half-way through the shoot) and [this one](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/X-Men-Days-Future-Past-Almost-Included-Young-Juggernaut-42085.html) talks about how Joshn Helman was originally cast as Juggernaut and changed to William Stryker at the last minute.

Comment: It's also because the character is a walking deus ex machina. His powers are essentially god-like and would kill any scene.

Comment: I was a school night.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The film's writer, Simon Kinsberg addressed this point in a [podcast interview](http://www.empireonline.com/news/story.asp?NID=41130) for Empire Magazine (39:24)

> "When asked why the X-Men didn’t take Quicksilver to Paris with them,
>   Kinberg answered, **“I love that people are asking this question,
>   because I think it comes from people loving Evan Peters in the film.
>   It was just a story decision. They go to Peter to help them with one
>   mission to break Erik out of prison. He completes the mission so he’s
>   done for this film…”**

---

Out of universe, the reason is far more mundane. The scenes in Paris were written and scripted (and partially filmed) before the character of Quicksilver was ever added to the film, presumably as a way of preventing Marvel from taking [full ownership of the rights](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/X-Men-Days-Future-Past-Adds-Evan-Peters-Quicksilver-37721.html) to the character.

The only way they could add him to the cast was to write an entirely new scene which they could then place at the start of the film and hope that the film's viewers didn't notice that he simply disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Given Quicksilver's awesome power, him being in Paris would have killed a lot of the suspense in those scenes. And like others said, Quicksilver was a late addition to the film, so they weren't going to reshoot the movie just to include him everywhere.

However, if you want an "in-story" explanation, maybe Wolverine and Xavier felt he was too young. He looked to be a highschooler, and his mother would surely freak out if some random guys decided to take him to Paris. Also, Quicksilver has had run ins with the law, so maybe Xavier didn't want to deal with his compulsive stealing and hyperactivity for a prolonged period.

Comment: This seems quite speculative. They didn't consist him too young to drive across America and break into a high security installation